# How do I tell MS Flow to create a table using the last cell in the table range field?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I get a bunch of .xlsx files sent to a shared mailbox, and I plan to wrangle the management of these in Flow. If these reports had pre-defined tables it'd be super easy, but they don't, so I have to create the table first after saving the file to Sharepoint, which should be pretty easy - except apparently I'm a moron and consequently, it ain't.

Connector: Excel Online (Business)
Action: Create Table
Field: Table range

The Microsoft support info doesn't help a lot, but *does* specify it needs to use A1 notation, which is where I assume my first attempt fell over (I'd tried to use a formula to define the range).

In VBA I'd use old mate lrow when naming the range, so it'd end up something like this, which gives you a good idea of what I'm aiming at:

["RC:R"&lRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b82Xr.png)

But no matter what flavour of input I punch in, Flow just won't accept anything I throw at it to make that row number dynamic.

Any ideas?